# Getting JSON values in Node JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a JSON response from TMDB:

```json
{
  "id": 283350,
  "results": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "BR",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "12",
          "iso_639_1": "pt",
          "note": "Streaming",
          "release_date": "2017-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "GB",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "12",
          "iso_639_1": "en",
          "release_date": "2015-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "SG",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2015-12-17T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "TR",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2015-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "AU",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "M",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "release_date": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "PH",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "PG-13",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2015-05-21T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "KR",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "15세이상관람가",
          "iso_639_1": "en",
          "release_date": "2015-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "GR",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "13",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "CA",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "2014-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now what i really need is to get the certification only from the US, so i would get PG-13. 
But for some reason whatever i do seems to just return undefined and will not match with the US, the only way i got this to work was showing only [6] which is fine, but US will not always be #6

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you are missing your javascript code for this question to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.find()` to find the object with `US` certification. The `Array.find()` method will find a value that matches the given condition. In your case `iso_3166_1` should have value of `US`.

```js
var data = {
  "id": 283350,
  "results": [{
    "iso_3166_1": "BR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "12",
      "iso_639_1": "pt",
      "note": "Streaming",
      "release_date": "2017-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 4
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "GB",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "12",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "release_date": "2015-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 4
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "SG",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-12-17T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "TR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "AU",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "M",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "release_date": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 5
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "PH",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "US",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "PG-13",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-05-21T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "KR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "15세이상관람가",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "release_date": "2015-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "GR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "13",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "CA",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2014-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }]
};

var USCertification = data.results.find(({iso_3166_1}) => iso_3166_1 == 'US');
console.log(USCertification);
console.log(USCertification.release_dates[0].certification);
```

**USING PLAIN FUNCTION**

```js
var data = {
  "id": 283350,
  "results": [{
    "iso_3166_1": "BR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "12",
      "iso_639_1": "pt",
      "note": "Streaming",
      "release_date": "2017-10-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 4
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "GB",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "12",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "release_date": "2015-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 4
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "SG",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-12-17T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "TR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "AU",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "M",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "release_date": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 5
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "PH",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "US",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "PG-13",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-05-21T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "KR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "15세이상관람가",
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "release_date": "2015-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "GR",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "13",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }, {
    "iso_3166_1": "CA",
    "release_dates": [{
      "certification": "",
      "iso_639_1": "",
      "note": "",
      "release_date": "2014-09-11T00:00:00.000Z",
      "type": 3
    }]
  }]
};

var USCertification = data.results.find(function(obj){
  return obj.iso_3166_1 === 'US';
});
console.log(USCertification);
console.log(USCertification.release_dates[0].certification);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @ThomasPetersen glad to help